# How to use pdfMake with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdfmake

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to use pdfMake, I can use it with static data but not able to achieve this with dynamic data, I would appreciate if you can help me achieve this it would be great, as I've searched all over the internet and couldn't quite get how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

employees.component.ts

```
getAllEmployees(){
    this.restService.GetAllEmployees().subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.employees = res.data.employees
    for(var i = 0; i< this.employees.length; i++) {
    this.array = this.employees[i]
    console.log(this.array)
    }
  })
}

generatePdf(){
  const documentDefinition = this.getDocumentDefinition();
  pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open();
}

getDocumentDefinition() {
  return {
    content: [
        {
        table: {
          headerRows: 4,
          widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],
          body: [
            [ 'Name', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
            [ this.array.firstName_FL, 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
          ]
        }
      }
    ]    
  };
}
ExportAsPDF(){
  this.generatePdf();
}
```

I've tried using this.array.firstName_FL however it comes up with last index only

Comment: Looking at the source code provided, `this.array` will hold the last employee (for loop will execute and on every cycle will assign employee[i] to your `this.array`). You will need to dynamically inject the array of elements within the `content[0].table.body` starting with index 1.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I apologize I'm a newbie, can you please explain how to put this piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. Please note that this wasn't tested.

```
getDocumentDefinition() {
    return {
        content: [
            {
            table: {
            headerRows: 4,
            widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],
            body: [[ 'Name', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ]]
                .concat(this.employees.map((el, i) => [el.firstName_FL, el['secondPropHere'], el['thirdPropHere'], el['fourthPropHere']]))
            }
        }
        ]    
    };
}
```

Sorry for the formatting, let me know if that works. The whole idea behind it is that, in the end, `body` needs to be an array of arrays:

- first array would be the header (as in thead/tr/th)
- second array would be the first data row (as in tbody/tr/td)
- third array -> the second data row, etc

Concat will just return a new array containing the header array and followed by arrays of each employee data (the `map` high order function).

```
el['secondPropHere'] - just remove square brackets and use the dot notation to get your desired property for the second prop, like `el.secondProp`.
```

Comment: I've tried the above but it came up with an error this.array.map is not a function

Comment: I've updated it, instead of `array` it should have been `employees`. Please read further about map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: It is working just the way I wanted, I can't thank you enough my friend

Comment: Glad it helped!